# what to pass as key instead of username and password for anonymous users in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a mongodb schema in which i am allowing the person to publish projects anonymously, i already have the authenticated user schema and i am thinking of using that only to allow users to publish their projects! any idea on how should i proceed ?

for example : like what should be the authenticity for anonymous user, should it be a same key for all users, or different key for every user etc... i am fairly new to database and i am confused. any suggestions to me ?
schema user :

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  full_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  projects: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "projects" }]
});
```

thankyou

Comment: One question, you want an anonymous user to publish a project, or do you want a registered user (with login and password) to publish a project anonymously?

Comment: anonymous user to publish project and data should be stored in db

Comment: for anonymous users just scrap the concept of the user model. Allow your projects to be created without a user

Comment: is this okay security wise ?

Comment: @DanStarns is this the right way to do ?

Comment: well if the user is anonymous, how can you relate them to the User model? you cant... maybe add a field on 'Project' like 'Project.anonymous' = Boolean. It does mean that your endpoints for creating a Project will have to be unprotected.

Comment: okay i will try that, will it have security issue though ?

Comment: @Raju it depends on what you're storing on a project, I would advise against storing files but simple JSON objects are fine.

Comment: thankyou bro, i will also take ur advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every document in mongodb has a unique _id field generated automatically, so you can use that field to identify every anonymous user.

My suggestion is to use cookies to authenticate the user, you can use a library like `passport.js` to validate the user and save its mongodb unique _id, so when this user sends a request to your server you can get its _id with something like this `req.user._id`.

One possible disadvantage is that when an anonymous user clears his cookies, he loses authentication and thus loses access to his projects.

Comment: then, no sir, i don't want the data to be lost. Can you look at  @DanStarns  comment

Comment: The data in the database won't be lost, just the anonymous user won't be able to track its projects because his lost his authentication, for example, if you want everyone to see all anonymous projects, then you don't need to validate the user at all, just put some identifier on the project schema to show this project  don't have a user

Comment: oh right i have a gallery.page  ,so i guess it's okay then .